# Android Chrome constantly crashing with my HTML5 website -- How to debug it?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

i have built a HTML5 web site (or rather webapp as you wish) and it works fine in Chrome and firefox. I would say the only thing out of the ordinary is, that it uses

- Google Closure in some parts (the issue persists in the simplest, non-optimized mode)
- HTML5 canvas for 2D drawing

Now I was curious whether it would run on my Galaxy Tab Tablett and indeed it does. I was able to set up the remote debugging facility https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging?hl=de and debug my code to get rid of a few things that were not working properly. However I notice that android-chrome regulary crashes while I use my app. The console in my desktop browser then complains about websocket being closed (thats why I suspect it really is a problem of the tablet side).

I would like to know what makes my website crash and am a bit flubbergusted that my HTML/js site can crash a browser like chrome so easily. I would have thought that it should be more stable than that.

Now as I would like to have an "entry" point into debugging the issue:

- is there a crash log of chrome for android that I can inspect somehow?
- can I somehow make it (chrome or android in general) more verbose on error messages?

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome for Android isn't the most stable thing on Earth. It may be a genuine browser defect. When it crashes do you use the crash reporter? That should get it on their list of things to fix. Does the issue occur with other browsers, like Android Browser or Firefox for Android (Fennec)?

Comment: Perhaps try some logging, if the app doesn't crash instantaneously you should be able to at least get an idea of where it is crashing. Also, how are you utilizing Closure?

Comment: I now feel like the problem is related to the USB Web Debug connection with Desktop-Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can do:

- chrome://crashes will list the crashes that it has caught when a tab crashes - you might need to turn on crash reporting in the settings.  You won't be able to fix it but you will be able to report it us so we can see if it is an issue.
- Use logcat and see if there are any specific issues in the tracing output, such as an out of error message.